# Adjusting labels on bar chart ggplot2, non-dependent on data value

Tags: r

I added labels to my bar chart using hjust, but for some reason they are farther away for the bars that have higher values. Ideally I want them all to be rather close to each bar.

```
plot_snpEff_annotations <- ggplot(plot_METTL14_can_exome_annotations, aes(plot_METTL14_can_exome_annotations$snpEff_Annotation)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", color = "black", fill=my_palette) +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label = ..count.., hjust = -1), stat="count", size = 3) +
  labs(title = "Types of Variants in METTL14", subtitle = "snpEff Annotation", 
       x = "Count", y = "Variant Type")
plot_snpEff_annotations
```

[image: Image1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hjust` varies between 0 and 1, generally, with 0.5 being center justified. I'd recommend setting `hjust = 0` and then using the `nudge` adjusters to tweak the amount in data coordinates. For example:

```
ggplot(data.frame(a = letters[1:3], b = 1:3), aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = b^3), hjust = 0, nudge_y = 0.05) +
  coord_flip()
```

The reason your `hjust` behaves not as you expect: the text is "anchored" at the data coordinate. If you set `hjust = 0`, it will be left justified, with that point as the marge. With `hjust = 0.5`, the center of the text will be that point, and `hjust = 1` will be right-justified with that point as the margin. The scale is linear, and longer text needs to move farther than shorter text to go from left to right justification, and when you go beyond the (0, 1) interval it continues at the same rate.